# Replacing with java regex

Tags: java, regex

```
String str = "abcde123_92qwq_1a_02x_1e";
```

I want to replace the first string part between the first two underscores (**92qwq**) with 0 (zero). How can I do this with regex?

For example:
"abcde123_**92qwq**_1a_02x_1e" becomes "abcde123_**0**_1a_02x_1e"
"abcde123_**sdet4**_1a_02x_1e" becomes "abcde123_**0**_1a_02x_1e"

I'm a newbie to the regex and I have tried a few. But I'm in a kind of bit urgent situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
str = str.replaceFirst("_[^_]+_", "_o_");
```

Comment: +1 for showing that string.replace supports RegEx (I didn't know that).

Comment: @0xCAFEBABE, sorry it doesn't, it's `replaceFirst()`.

Comment: Thanx very much Qtax. It's working perfectly.Better if you can change ' to ". :)